# Looking for a quote about the importance of writing about women's stories, no matter how 'small' they are

Tags: quote-source

I had a read a quote a long time ago by a famous author who was talking about how she was asked why she thought she should write about something as 'insignificant' as women talking in rooms when she could write about something as 'significant' as men fighting in wars (I'm not exactly sure if this is the comparison).
Ultimately the quote was about her saying that women talking in rooms is definitely as significant.
What is this quote? Who said it? I've been searching forever and I have no idea who wrote this (I thought it was Virginia Woolf for a while, but nothing's really turning up).